# webkit translateX animation is rolling back to initial position

Tags: webkit, css

I am trying to do a images gallery for mobile webkit,

The only way it is actually fast enough is using the hardware accelerated  translateX .

My problem is that the div take back its initial position at the end of the animation. I add the slideGalLeft class cliking on the left button. to the animated div

You can see an example here, in the callback events section:
http://position-absolute.com/jqtouch/demos/main/#home

```
    .slideGalLeft {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideColis;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slideColis {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    to { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do not use webkit animation for this as it comes back to the default values once played.
Instead define

```
.slideGalleft{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

and using Javascript, either set `-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);` or add a CSS class to your element which set the final transform value and webkit will animate it properly

Comment: you can use animation fill-mode to keep the animation at the last position (although you should really be using transition for a permanent one step change)

Comment: You are definitely right about fill-mode property. I did not know it at the time of my answer.

Comment: I tried overflow-x: hidden; on both the body and html that dident work for safari -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); worked many thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

Guillaume's answer is great.  However, if you are looking for hardware acceleration, you must let the webkit engine know you want 3D rendering (what makes hardware acceleration active).

According to http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/speed/html5/#toc-hardware-accell, this is done by adding translateZ(0) to your rule, like so:

```
.slideGalleft{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) translateZ(0);
}
```

Follow Guillaume's advice beyond that.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none/backwards/forwards/both;
```

This allows you to define at what end of your animation the element remains when the animation is finished.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work by adding a "display:none" style on the finish of the animation. Use the following CSS:

```
.paused {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

.hiddendiv {
    display:none;
}
```

Then in your jQuery code:

```
$('div.sideimage').click(
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("paused").delay(2000).queue(
            function(next) {     
                $(this).addClass("hiddendiv");     
                next();
            }
        ); 
    }
);
```

Should work!