# How can I let my css3 animation to stay at its animated position when it finishes animating?

Tags: css, css-animations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Webkit CSS Animation issue - persisting the end state of the animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273478/webkit-css-animation-issue-persisting-the-end-state-of-the-animation)

I want to keep the position of my animated div when it finishes running. Right now I animating the div on mouse hover, but the div return back to it's position even if I'm still hovering over it.

Is there a way to let it get back only when I mouse out?

http://jsfiddle.net/neoswf/X5a64/

```
div{
    width:100px;height:100px;margin:1em;background:red
}
div:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotateThis;
  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateThis {
  from { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform:scale(1.1) rotate(100deg); }
}​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/X5a64/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to persist the end state:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stjHZ/