# CSS3 Slide Out Animation on Page Load

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to get an image to slide out to the left when the page loads using purely CSS.

So, far I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/o7thwd/qZbhJ/ and it seems to work.  The issue I can't seem to get over is how the image comes back into view once the animation is over.

```
#slide {
    left:0;
    width:268px;    
    -moz-animation-name: slideOut;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: once;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideOut;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: once;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -o-animation-name: slideOut;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: once;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: slideOut;
    animation-iteration-count: once;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-duration: 1.5s; 
}
@-o-keyframes slideOut {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: -268px;
    }
}
@keyframes slideOut {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: -268px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideOut {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: -268px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideOut {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: -268px;
    }
}
```

How can I get it to stay folded to the left like it does on initial page load?

Comment: have you thought about just hiding it with `display: none;`

Comment: yes, but I need the animation...  hence why I am asking...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273478/webkit-css-animation-issue-persisting-the-end-state-of-the-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you add the following CSS `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` and the animation end will be persistent rather than revert back to the original.

**[WORKING JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qZbhJ/1/)**

Oh and you only need to use the `-webkit-` vendor specific for animations there are no `-moz-` or `-o-` vendor specifics for animations

CSS:

```
#slide {
    left:0;
    width:268px;    
    -webkit-animation-name: slideOut;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: once;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;   
    animation-name: slideOut;
    animation-iteration-count: once;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slideOut {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: -268px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideOut {
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        left: -268px;
    }
}
```