# XML SVG - persist the end state of an animation

Tags: svg, svg-animate

After the end of an [`AnimateTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform) action, the element snaps back to the original value.
  This isn't exactly unexpected as it's in the [SMIL documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#AnimationElements):

> As with all animation elements, this only manipulates the presentation value, and when the animation completes, the effect is no longer applied

But it is unwanted. I'd like to find a way to persist the changes using XML animations

#### Here's an example in SVG

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect id="outline" stroke="black" fill="white" 
        width="100" height="100" >
    <animateTransform id="one"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      attributeName="transform"
                      type="translate"
                      from="0" to="-7"
                      dur="1s" repeatCount="1" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

One idea I had was to call a [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/set) action with [`dur="indefinite"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dur) that was triggered by the end of the first animation with [begin="one.end"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin), but can't quite seem to get the syntax right.  I haven't found any documentation that show how to call `set` for a transformed value.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect id="outline" stroke="black" fill="white" 
        width="100" height="100" >
    <animateTransform id="one"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      attributeName="transform"
                      type="translate"
                      from="0" to="-7"
                      dur="1s" repeatCount="1" />
    
    <!-- Doesn't work -->
    <set attributeType="XML"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="translate"
         to="-7" begin="one.end" /> 
    
    <!-- Does work (as POC) -->
    <set attributeType="css"
         attributeName="fill"
         to="green" begin="one.end" />

  </rect>
</svg>
```

This question on [persisting the end state of the animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3273478/1366033) shows how to do this with css transforms by using `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;`, but that obviously won't have any affect on an svg animation

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[fill="freeze"](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#TimingAttributes) will persist the state of an animation e.g.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect id="outline" stroke="black" fill="white" 
        width="100" height="100" >
    <animateTransform id="one"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      attributeName="transform"
                      type="translate"
                      from="0" to="-7"
                      dur="1s" repeatCount="1"
                      fill="freeze"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```